# Sequence and Biggest,Smallest with vector

Tags: c++

The question says that show the highest and lowest number of that sequence and the number of times that they appear. I now i need to show how many numbers this sequence appears,also they need to be lesser than 2000:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int v[11], i, b, l;
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    b = v[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
       if (v[i] > b)
            b = v[i];
        i++;
    }
    l = v[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (v[i] < l)
            l = v[i];
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    return 0;
}
```

And see the input and output how should they appear

```
Input:
20
40
39
120
2
200
2
360
780
7
2

Output:
biggest:780 Shows 1 time(s)
lowest:2 Shows 3 time(s)
```

Comment: This is way too complicated, the optimal solution is much simpler, and has exactly one `for` loop. Only one `for` loop is needed to determine all of this. And the solution will not require the use of any array, and can trivially make all these calculations on the fly, reading one value at a time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What he's doing is fine. The focus should be on understanding how to solve the problem. He can optimize later.

Comment: That's the problem you need to solve. What is your question for us? Did the code not work the way you intended it to? Did it fail to compile? Please give us the relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for the maximum integer. Use similar method for the minimum integer.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int v[11]; // gets the input array
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] > max)
        {
            max = v[i];
            count = 1;
        } else if (v[i] == max)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

The first for loop gets the input from the user. I haven't changed this part of the code.

The second for loop is where the magic happens. First, we define a maximum variable and a count variable. Both variables are set to zero.

As the for loop iterates through the array, we do some if-statements. First, we check whether the current element is greater than our maximum variable. If this is true, we have found a new maximum variable, so we set max = the current element. We also change the value of count to one, because we have found only one instance so far of the new maximum.

We also check if the current element is equal to the maximum. In this case, we have found another instance of the maximum element so we increment count by 1.

These are the only two cases we have to check. It is simple to apply similar logic for the minimum element.

Comment: That's not much better than a code-only answer. Could you describe the method instead of relying on the ability of someone with this question to read code?

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my answer now.

Comment: So how this code should appear because i did the same with min and changed if (v[i] > max) to if (v[i] < min), and this dont show how many times a number appears, if possible make the complete code because using this code only dont show how many times the max appears.

Comment: @shioares the variable count represents how many times the maximum element appears. To count minimum you need to do (v[i] < min) and (v[i] == min) for the two cases. Try writing your own program based on my code and update the question if you can’t do it.

Comment: @shioares Could you update the question with your code? I could help you better then.

Answer (score -1):

So here's what i did but still doesn't work what could it be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int v[11],i; // gets the input array
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}

int max = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    if (v[i] > max)
    {
        max = v[i];
        count = 1;
    } else if (v[i] == max)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
int min = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    if (v[i] < min)
    {
        min = v[i];
        count = 1;
    } else if (v[i] == min)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", max);
printf("%d\n", min);
}
```